# Typescript generic type for all variables defined

Tags: javascript, class, interface, typescript, definition

I have an object like below:

```
var objContainer = {};
objContainer.string1 = "some string";
objContainer.string2 = "some string";
....
objContainer.stringN = "some string";
```

I want to create a type for objContainer variable in TypeScript.The point is, the variable count and names are unknown. So, I want to introduce a logic like "for each variable inside objContainer's type class will be string type, disregarding its name". Is there any way to accomplish that? Pseudo-code example is:

```
interface ExampleInterface{
   objContainer:ExampleClass;
}
class ExampleClass{
   {All Variables}:string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to use interface like this:

```
interface Map 
{
    [K: string]: string;
}

let dict: Map = {};
dict["string1"] = "some string";
let val = dict["string1"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. However, this solution needs a conversion of typing. I had to change all codes 
objContainer.string1 = "some string"; to 
objContainer["string1"] = "some string";. Then it worked. Just to know, would it be possible to do it without changing the structure of existing implementation?

Comment: I am afraid - no. If you want type assertion and do not know your properties in advance. Otherwise you can always fall back by casting your objContainer to "any" like this: let o = <any>objContainer. And from that access its properties in the original  unsafe manner: o.string1 = '111'.